# Alignment across several `tabular` blocks

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

So, in the following code, the cells in the first and second sections will be on a different horizontal level. How would I align them? I want both to be on the same level as the cells in the first section. The left hand side of the second section should also align to the right. How would I accomplish this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\begin{tabular}{rl} 
 \textsc{September} 2014 --- \textsc{May} 2018 & Cell 1\\
                                               & Cell 2\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Second Section}
\begin{tabular}{rl}

 \textsc{May} 2014 --- \textsc{May} 2018 & Cell 3\\
                                         & Cell 4\\
 \textsc{May} 2006 --- \textsc{May} 2028 & Cell 5\\
                                         & Cell 6\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could add `\usepackage{array}` and replace the `r` in you column definitions with `>{\raggedleft}p{15em}`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht alright, thanks! The answer below worked well for me, but I will keep this in mind.

Comment: There are different ways to accomplish this. The answers below are perhaps better, because there you don’t need to know the length of the stuff in the first column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome! You can use the `eqparbox` package to synchronize the widths.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\begin{tabular}{rl} 
 \eqmakebox[A][r]{\textsc{September} 2014 --- \textsc{May} 2018} & Cell 1\\
                                               & Cell 2\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Second Section}
\begin{tabular}{rl}

 \eqmakebox[A][r]{\textsc{May} 2014 --- \textsc{May} 2018} & Cell 3\\
                                         & Cell 4\\
 \eqmakebox[A][r]{\textsc{May} 2006 --- \textsc{May} 2028} & Cell 5\\
                                         & Cell 6\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also introduce a new column type, called `Q` here, that makes the width equal. Then you need only to use this type.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{array}
\newbox\eqtabbox
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\setbox\eqtabbox=\hbox\bgroup}r<{\egroup
\eqmakebox[Q][r]{\copy\eqtabbox}}}
\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\begin{tabular}{Ql} 
 \textsc{September} 2014 --- \textsc{May} 2018 & Cell 1\\
                                               & Cell 2\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Second Section}
\begin{tabular}{Ql}

 \textsc{May} 2014 --- \textsc{May} 2018 & Cell 3\\
                                         & Cell 4\\
 \textsc{May} 2006 --- \textsc{May} 2028 & Cell 5\\
                                         & Cell 6\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You can also let `Q` take an argument that indicates the alignment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{array}
\newbox\eqtabbox
\newcolumntype{Q}[1]{>{\setbox\eqtabbox=\hbox\bgroup}#1<{\egroup
\eqmakebox[Q][#1]{\copy\eqtabbox}}}
\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\begin{tabular}{Q{r}l} 
 \textsc{September} 2014 --- \textsc{May} 2018 & Cell 1\\
                                               & Cell 2\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Second Section}
\begin{tabular}{Q{r}l}

 \textsc{May} 2014 --- \textsc{May} 2018 & Cell 3\\
                                         & Cell 4\\
 \textsc{May} 2006 --- \textsc{May} 2028 & Cell 5\\
                                         & Cell 6\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Or two arguments, where the first one is an identifier in case you have different columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{array}
\newbox\eqtabbox
\newcolumntype{Q}[2]{>{\setbox\eqtabbox=\hbox\bgroup}#2<{\egroup
\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{\copy\eqtabbox}}}
\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\begin{tabular}{Q{A}{r}l} 
 \textsc{September} 2014 --- \textsc{May} 2018 & Cell 1\\
                                               & Cell 2\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Second Section}
\begin{tabular}{Q{A}{r}l}

 \textsc{May} 2014 --- \textsc{May} 2018 & Cell 3\\
                                         & Cell 4\\
 \textsc{May} 2006 --- \textsc{May} 2028 & Cell 5\\
                                         & Cell 6\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: @user3496846 You should use `@{}` at the start and end of the tabular preamble to line up what inside the tabular to the text inside. No all cells in first row is are indented from left margin with `\tabcolsep`. The same is true if you have justified text in the last column, it will be indented from the right margin with a `\tabcolsep`.